# setInterval with jquery.idle

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have no idea what I missing in this script - it should use the jQuery library 'idle' to detect no activity - in which case the time should be stopped and requests to server are not made.

The "Idle"  event fires (as does active) but the timer used to call the AJAX request never stops - WTF>?!?!

```

```
    <script>
        var minTaskUpdateInterval = 1000 * 30; // 30 second intervals 

        function initTaskTimeTracking()
        {
            Ext.Ajax.request({
                url: 'service/application/task/updatetimer',
                params: {interval: minTaskUpdateInterval}
            });
        }

        var intervalId = 0;

        idle({
            idle: 10000, // NOTE: IDLE notification when
            onIdle: function () {
                clearInterval(intervalId);
                console.log('Idle');
            },
            onActive: function () {
                intervalId = setInterval(initTaskTimeTracking, 5000);
                console.log('Active');
            }
        }).start();
    </script>
```

```

Comment: is onActive called more than once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is onActive is called more than once so you get multiple timers running. So detect if you have a interval before running it again.

```
 var intervalId;

    idle({
        idle: 10000, // NOTE: IDLE notification when
        onIdle: function () {
            clearInterval(intervalId);
            intervalId = false;
            console.log('Idle');
        },
        onActive: function () {
            if (!intervalId) {
              intervalId = setInterval(initTaskTimeTracking, 5000);
            }
            console.log('Active');
        }
    }).start();
```

Comment: That was it. "Idle" is indeed being called twice - the console.log having shown two each event fire should have tipped me off - always appreciate a second set of eyes on a frustrating issue :) thanks man!